# Программное устранение дребезга контактов на AVR на прошивке zabbuino

Tags: arduino, avr

Есть мк Atmega328P + ethernet - модуль wiznet w5100
и прошивка zabbuino (для работы по протоколу zabbix)
https://github.com/zbx-sadman/zabbuino/wiki/Zabbuino-in-Russian-(for-release-1.4.x)
https://github.com/zbx-sadman/zabbuino.git
Сеть настроил, команды утилитой `zabbix_get` успешно отправляются и мк на них отвечает по сети.
Подключил тактовую кнопку на PD2 (INT0). Задача - увеличивать счетчик по нажатию на кнопку, для этого есть команда `extInt.count[intPin, mode]`, которая возвращает количество событий прерывания.
Но бывает, срабатывает 2-4 прерывания вместо 1. Каким образом, используя эту функцию сделать защиту от дребезга программно?

Answer (score 0):

Чтобы дребезг контакта не влиял на данные при опросе кнопки, её состояние следует опрашивать раз с частотой около 32 Гц.

```
#include <ve_avr.h>  

volatile bool bScanKeyboard = false;  

void setup() 
{
   DEV_TIMER2.setClockSelect(Prescaler2::Prescaler_1024);    // 16 MГц / 1024 = 15625 Гц
   DEV_TIMER2.setWaveGenMode(Timer2::Normal);
   DEV_TICTRL2.overflowIntEnable();                          // 15625 Гц / 256 = 61 Гц
   interrupts(); 
}  

void loop() 
{
   if (bScanKeyboard) {
     bScanKeyboard = false;
     scanKeyboard();
   } 
}  

void scanKeyboard() 
{
   // TODO: Keyboard scan code 
}  

ISR(TIMER2_OVF_vect) 
{
   bScanKeyboard = true; 
}
```